# Write python dictionary into textfile

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I want to write my python dictionary in a text file where each line contain one key and its value, with comma as separation. I am using the following code:

```
with open(compounds, 'w') as f:
    for key, value in dict_NTID_IDs_in_EisDatabase.items():
        f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

But it returns me the following error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Looks like `compounds` is a list. Use a string instead.

Comment: no, compounds is a textfile

Comment: Since an os.PathLike object is expected, this suggests the exception comes from open(). What's the type of 'compounds'?

Comment: @smvpfm, you're using a `:` as a separator. What does key/value look like in `dict_NTID_IDs_in_EisDatabase`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that compounds, where you initialize it, cannot be interpreted as a file path because it's a list.
Put this before that code:

`compounds = "my_dict.txt"`

This will write your dictionary in a file in the directory you're in. You can check the directory you're in, or change it with the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this :

```
with open(compounds, 'w') as f:
    for key, value in zip(dict_NTID_IDs_in_EisDatabase.keys(), dict_NTID_IDs_in_EisDatabase.values()):
        f.write('%s,%s\n' % (key, value))
```

You can also use `dict.items()` as you mentionned but `dict.items()` returns a `tuple` `((key0, value0), (key1, value1) ...)`.

To get back to your question, you can use :

```
with open(compounds, 'w') as f:
    for item in dict_NTID_IDs_in_EisDatabase.items():
        f.write('%s,%s\n' % (item[0], item[1]))
```

Comment: I get this error expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: I changed the name of the file and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you!

```
dic = {'Python' : '.py', 'C++' : '.cpp', 'Java' : '.java'}
f = open("dic.txt","w")
f.write( str(dic) )
f.close()
```